# My IP address continuously changes on my mobile phone

Tags: ip, mobile-phone

My IP address continuously changes as I go from one place to another on my mobile phone.

So say for example in Cape Town it is

```
123.456.7890
```

But for example in Johannesburg it is

```
111.222.3333
```

(Not really, just example)

How does it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IP address serves two principal functions: **host or network interface identification** and **location addressing**.Its role has been characterized as follows: "A name indicates what we seek. **An address indicates where it is**. A route indicates how to get there."

- [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)

Answer (score 0):

An IP address changes if you go to another place, because there's different towers (cellphone network towers) in different places so that is how it changes.